# Unable to recognize RETRY UNTIL definition

Tags: karate

I am trying to implement the retry until functionality in a feature.

```
    Scenario: Send a valid request and verify response status = 200
        Given path requestPath
        And configure retry = { count: 10, interval: 5000 }
        And retry until responseStatus == 200
        When method get
```

However the step remains undefined in my ide. I have tried the following:

- Updating to latest intelliJ Community 2018.3
- invalidated cache and restarted intelliJ
- uninstalled and reinstalled Cucumber for Java
- verify Gherkin plugin installed.
- verified test folder is marked as Test Sources root
- tried using Karate 0.9.0.RC3

What else can I try to make the squiggly line go away?!?[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8mS4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest Karate 0.9.0 (final).

Comment: I deleted karate from local .m2, changed karate version to 0.9.1 and re-imported.  Tested at Scenario, Backround, karate-config.js, and karate-base.js levels.  Works perfectly.  Thank you.